# Xmpp chat messages are not updating for the 2nd time opening that activity

Tags: android, listview, xmpp, android-adapter, smack

I am working on a `xmpp` chat application for android using smack lib.

1. for chat I am storing all the chat messages in the database.

When ever I get a incoming chat message and and when ever I send a message to friends I am storing in db.

```
datebasehandler.insertConversionsMessages(messageModel);
```

with some ID conversations.

Creating `xmpp` connetions and setconnection is done in login activity where `xmpp` connection is created .

I don't have a problem is receiving and send the messages.

For 1st time I open ChatActivity that time I load the previous chat messages of whom I am chating with in a `ListView`
(ListView with CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter)

When I send a message, I will add the item to arraylist
and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
so it is updated to the listview

For incoming messages from this "with-user" I'm chatting with to be updated in the database and I'm getting from the database and I'm updating the list-view.

For the 1st time every thing works fine and well.

But I go back and open this chat activity to chat again, this time few incoming messages are not updating to the UI i,e list-view.

I tried with all the possible things with list-view and adapters

===> when it is not updating if i press on edit-text soft-keyboard pops up and then I close it . Now if I scroll the list at the bottom they are updated.

===> If without opening and closing soft-keyboard try to pull the list means its not updated in the list-view. But if I click on any row I will
    then I'll get a error

The content of the adapter has changed but `ListView` did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notify-data...etc

Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly tell you not to update UI from background thread. use `performOnUiThread` Activity instance method to call `notifyDatasetChanged()`